# What does blue highlight mean in notepad++ when writing a script file (.sh)?

Tags: notepad++

What does blue highlight mean in Notepad++ when writing a Unix script file (.sh)?

For example, in:

```
for i in {0..16};do (awk '/AvgSeqDepth/ {while (getline > 0) print $3}' `${array[$i]}`) >> bashlines.txt;done
```

`${array[$i]}` is highlighted as blue in Notepad++.

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what blue highlight?

Comment: Settings->Style configurator, then select "bash" in the language list and click through the styles until you find the blue you mean. Then you know the name of the style. If it is unclear what it means, ask here again :)

Comment: Thanks for being more specific. I've updated my answer to reflect the new info. Although, I would say the color is more `teal` than `blue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open up **Settings > Style Configurator**, you can inspect and customize a language's styles and syntax. Regarding **Bash**, `intruction words` or commands are highlighted as [blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue) (`#0000FF`) by default.

[image: style configurator]

The list of keywords includes:

> alias ar asa awk banner basename bash bc bdiff break bunzip2 bzip2 cal
>   calendar case cat cc cd chmod cksum clear cmp col comm compress
>   continue cp cpio crypt csplit ctags cut date dc dd declare deroff dev
>   df diff diff3 dircmp dirname do done du echo ed egrep elif else env
>   esac eval ex exec exit expand export expr false fc fgrep fi file find
>   fmt fold for function functions getconf getopt getopts grep gres hash
>   head help history iconv id if in integer jobs join kill local lc let
>   line ln logname look ls m4 mail mailx make man mkdir more mt mv newgrp
>   nl nm nohup ntps od pack paste patch pathchk pax pcat perl pg pr print
>   printf ps pwd read readonly red return rev rm rmdir sed select set sh
>   shift size sleep sort spell split start stop strings strip stty sum
>   suspend sync tail tar tee test then time times touch tr trap true
>   tsort tty type typeset ulimit umask unalias uname uncompress unexpand
>   uniq unpack unset until uudecode uuencode vi vim vpax wait wc whence
>   which while who wpaste wstart xargs zcat

### Update:

You may also be referring to `parameters` which are highlighted with a foreground of [teal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teal) (`#008080`) and a background of [aqua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_%28color%29) (`#00FFFF`).

[image: parameters]